# Mention/Tag user functionality in social media app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am working on social media app and I want to add mention user or tag user functionality like Facebook and Instagram. I am using MERN stack for development. Please suggest me a method for adding this functionality.

Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use react mentions. Here is the link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mentions

Comment: Thank you soo much friend :) it helped me :D

Comment: @RaghavPatel you can also upvote it so that more people with this issue can reach it )

Comment: I am sorry, my rep points are low that's why I can not upvote.